# Unexpected simple simplexmlelement error

Tags: php, laravel, simplexml

When trying to access the simplexmlelement with PHP (second below). I use the following code `$candidate->result->recorddetail->FL[0]` and expect to be returned 2972941000000380012, but reach the (first below). I just need to reach this data = 2972941000000380012; Thank you

edit: when I access the FL array it doesn't just return the position i want.

```
    SimpleXMLElement {#360
  +"@attributes": array:1 [
    "val" => "Id"
  ]
  +0: "2972941000000380012"
}
```

when I return the string about, instead of reaching the destination I am received the second code block;

```
    SimpleXMLElement {#357
  +"@attributes": array:1 [
    "uri" => "/crm/private/xml/Contacts/insertRecords"
  ]
  +"result": SimpleXMLElement {#352
    +"message": "Record(s) updated successfully"
    +"recorddetail": SimpleXMLElement {#355
      +"FL": array:5 [
        0 => "2972941000000380012"
        1 => "2018-01-17 14:39:17"
        2 => "2018-01-17 15:11:49"
        3 => SimpleXMLElement {#368
          +"@attributes": array:1 [
            "val" => "Created By"
          ]
        }
        4 => SimpleXMLElement {#369
          +"@attributes": array:1 [
            "val" => "Modified By"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please could you [edit] the question to include a sample of the actual XML that leads to this object; the debug output from SimpleXML isn't always very helpful, and it will be easier if people can reproduce the problem for themselves. Please also include the exact PHP you are running on that XML. In other words, a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use (for example)...

```
$x = $candidate->result->recorddetail->FL[0];
```

This assigns the SimpleXMLElement and not the element value, which is what you really want.  You can fetch the value by casting this to a string, which will just return the elements content...

```
$x = (string)$candidate->result->recorddetail->FL[0];
```